# finding sequence of opcode in binary

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis, static-analysis

I have dis-assmebled binary and want to check if it contains particular sequence of opcodes(obtained from other reference binary). how to do that . i know plain byte
level comparison wont work as as memory address etc may differ.

```
example :
0000001806991C0                 push    rdi
.text:00000001806991C1                 sub     rsp, 30h
.text:00000001806991C5                 mov     [rsp+38h+var_18], 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh
.text:00000001806991CE                 mov     [rsp+38h+arg_0], rbx
.text:00000001806991D3                 mov     rdi, rcx
.text:00000001806991D6                 lea     rbx, [rcx+60h]
.text:00000001806991DA                 lea     rax, off_180B6BED0
.text:00000001806991E1                 mov     [rbx], rax
.text:00000001806991E4                 xor     r8d, r8d
.text:00000001806991E7                 lea     rdx, nullsub_1
.text:00000001806991EE                 mov     rcx, rbx
.text:00000001806991F1                 call    sub_1800A4160
.text:00000001806991F6                 mov     rcx, rbx
.text:00000001806991F9                 call    sub_1800A4148
.text:00000001806991FE                 xchg    ax, ax
.text:0000000180699200                 lea     rdx, sub_180259E24
.text:0000000180699207                 lea     rcx, [rdi+50h]
.text:000000018069920B                 call    sub_180079CEC
.text:0000000180699210                 lea     rcx, [rdi+50h]
.text:0000000180699214                 call    sub_1800A74C4
.text:0000000180699219                 lea     rax, off_180BE6328
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the specific instruction set encoding, *regular expressions* operating on the binary itself may be flexible enough to ignore the parts which would change based on address.

Piping the code through a naive disassembler and running the regular expression engine on the textual ouptut may be preferable to doing so on the binary as it's a lot easier to wire rules that ignore particular operands when they've been split out (though you would now be doing a multi-line match)

Sometimes it's not worth worrying about the *right* tool for the job, but just whipping up some code in your favorite language-of-convenience (today, probably python) to solve a one-time need.

It's also quite possible you could just do this with a text editor to find *part*  of the pattern and then manually check the candidates for a complete match./

Comment: i am new bie, could you tell some example regular expression for multiple instruction in IDA or in other tool. any example would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would disassembly, split off the instruction column, then diff, followed by manually comparing using side-by-side text editors (of the disassembled output of each) be fast and simple enough for a one off use.

Otherwise you need a *smart* comparison that knows that registers and memory locations can be interchanged for each other as long as each is consistent throughout; resulting in the same output - and thus each section of code having an identical function, those sections would be a copy of each other.

It depends on how much code you have to check and how often you intend to do this.

One advantage of the so-called smart comparison is that it can iterate over the code, shifting by one address, and find every possible way to match; resulting in a few false positives that need to be manually identified.

A disadvantage of relying on a disassembler is that it can miss (or go out of sync) and fail to disassemble a few sections of code; leaving some possible matches (or near matches) unfound - leading to a Copyright claim.

A program capable of an exhaustive comparison may be more useful than one that only discovers low hanging fruit. It's a matter of the intended end-use and the investment in the project necessary for the results that are expected to be had.

Comment: Are you suggesting manual comparison, code in which i am searching is quite big so some script in IDA or automated method would work only,

Comment: No I'm not, why?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to search a binary file for some sequence of binary values. Maybe I've misread and it's more complicated than that.

I'd start with good old grep.

```
cat binary.exe |  xxd -p | tr -d '\n' | grep -o -e '774b'
```

Send your binary through `xxd -p` to turn it into a hex string.

Remove the new lines with `tr -d '\n'`

The hand it off to `grep -o -e '774b'` to search for hex value `774b`.

The `-o` flag limits grep to only show the match, not the entire line (or file in this case as it's been turned into a single hex string line.

If you'd like to see some characters (bytes) before and after the match, add dots (`.`) for example `grep -o -e '....774b....'` to see 2 bytes before and 2 bytes after the match.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not necessary want to use IDA, you could use radare2 and then do:

```
radare2 <your_file>
```

then do:

```
/x <youropcodes>
```

.

Example:

```
/x 900a0b0c90
```

.

To get examples of how to use this command on radare2 you could use:

```
/x?
```

.

If you necessary want to use IDA pro for your knowledge, you could skip my answer.